# Interacting with quickpick in vscode extension api tests

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In my Markdown Full Text Search extension for VSCode I show search results in the QuickPick instance. In the automated test I want to run the command, which opens this QuickPick, and then simulate choosing the first item. Something like this:

```
  // this works well
  const result = await vscode.commands.executeCommand('markdown-search.search') as any;
  const quickPick = result.quickPick as vscode.QuickPick<vscode.QuickPickItem>;
  quickPick.value = 'test';
  // now the tricky part: how to "click" or "activate" the first item from items?
```

The most straightforward would be just to send the "Enter" key to the application window. Using something like "quickPick.accept(0);" is also acceptable. Unfortunately, it looks like there are no such ways. Have I overlooked something?

Comment: you have to mock the quick pick function and return the required element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VSCode some things you can do via API code and some things you can do via builtin commands.

So you can automate quick picks or completion widgets with commands. And you most probably looking for this:

```
vscode.commands.executeCommand('workbench.action.acceptSelectedQuickOpenItem')
```

There are other commands such as `workbench.action.quickOpenSelectNext`, you can full list of them by opening keyboard shortcuts (`keybindings.json`) and starting typing in the `command` property.

Comment: Thank you for your help with this. I've improved the tests for my extension.